# How to make user select "yes" from at least one of multiple select tags using jQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Using jQuery Validation Plugin, I am validating a form in following way. There are multiple select tags. They all have default "Select" value and 2 other options as "Yes" and "No". They are enabled or disabled dynamically when filling the form. User has to select "Yes" for at least one of the enabled select tags.

I have created a method using addMethod which does that. But it validates the same thing for every select element, and creates a separate error message for each one. Also, the error messages won't go away unless the user changes one of the options to "Yes" and then click on all other select elements.

I want to generate only one error message, which will go away as soon as user changes at least one select option to "Yes". Also the error highlight of all the tags should go away at once. Please help.

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML form -

```
<form name="new_registration" id="new_registration" method="post" action="">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="field_name">Parares</span>
        <span class="field_input">
            <span class="error" id="parares_error_output"></span>
            <select name="parares_a" id="parares_a" disabled="disabled">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
            <span>: A</span>
            <br />
            <select name="parares_b" id="parares_b" disabled="disabled">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
            <span>: B</span>
            <br />
            <select name="parares_c" id="parares_c" disabled="disabled">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
            <span>: C</span>
            <br />
            <select name="parares_d" id="parares_d" disabled="disabled">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
            <span>: D</span>
        </span>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <span class="field_input">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="sumbit">Submit</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery Validation Plugin code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        $.validator.addMethod("validateParares", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional( element ) ||
            ($('#parares_a').val() == 1 ||
            $('#parares_b').val() == 1 ||
            $('#parares_c').val() == 1 ||
            $('#parares_d').val() == 1);
        }, "Select proper parares<br />");

        var validator = $("#new_registration").validate({
            rules: {
                parares_a: {
                    validateParares: true,
                    min: 1,
                },
                parares_b: {
                    validateParares: true,
                    min: 1,
                },
                parares_c: {
                    validateParares: true,
                    min: 1,
                },
                parares_d: {
                    validateParares: true,
                    min: 1,
                }
            },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                if (element.attr("name") == "parares_a" ||
                    element.attr("name") == "parares_b" ||
                    element.attr("name") == "parares_c" ||
                    element.attr("name") == "parares_d") {
                    error.appendTo($('#parares_error_output'));
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
        });

        if(validator.form()){
            alert("This form seems valid. Click 'Ok' to submit.");
        }

    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r_yash/2f3end2L/)

Comment: would you mind create a jsfiddle for it ?

Comment: done. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have did few changes into your JavaScript so it will run fine with your code. 
Please replace your JavaScript code with below, also see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/2f3end2L/1/)

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateParares", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional( element ) ||
    ($('#parares_a').val() == 1 ||
    $('#parares_b').val() == 1 ||
    $('#parares_c').val() == 1 ||
    $('#parares_d').val() == 1);
}, "Select proper parares<br />");

$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#new_registration").validate({
        rules: {
            parares_a: {
                validateParares: true,
            }
        },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            if (element.attr("name") == "parares_a" ||
                element.attr("name") == "parares_b" ||
                element.attr("name") == "parares_c" ||
                element.attr("name") == "parares_d") {
                error.appendTo($('#parares_error_output'));
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
    });
    $("#submit").click(function(){

        if(validator.form()){
            alert("This form seems valid. Click 'Ok' to submit.");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: There are two problems: 1. Error message appears as soon as I select "No" in first tag and then click on any other tag. 2. Error message does not go away when I select "Yes" in any tag other than first one.

Comment: @user1543784 what is that?

Comment: @user1543784 Oh man it really confusing. you said as problems #1 is working in JSFiddle, problem #2 is really confuse me

Comment: I want at least one select to say "Yes". Naturally, when user changes ANY of the selects to "Yes" the error should go away.

Comment: It's great, except for the first problem. If I select "No" in first select, error message appears as soon as I click on any other select.

Comment: @user1543784 so you want must for 'Yes' in first select box, right?

Comment: I want error message to appear only when user has chosen "No" in all enabled selects. The message should not appear unless all selects are set to "No". And the message should go away as soon as any select is changed to "Yes". If user opts for "Yes" in at least any one select in the first go, then error message should not appear at all.

Comment: @user1543784 Look here i have take screenshot for all condition, which is working fine check out here http://snag.gy/dw7sw.jpg

Comment: I think the problem is because of disabled select. $('#parares_b').val() is always 0 (zero). And parares_c, parares_d are also 0 (zero) in the beginning. Hence when we check for val() == 1, no variable satisfies the condition and error gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, here's how I could solve it.

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateParares", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional( element ) ||
    (
    (($('#parares_a').val() != 2) && !($('#parares_a').prop('disabled'))) ||
    (($('#parares_b').val() != 2) && !($('#parares_b').prop('disabled'))) ||
    (($('#parares_c').val() != 2) && !($('#parares_c').prop('disabled'))) ||
    (($('#parares_d').val() != 2) && !($('#parares_d').prop('disabled')))
    );
}, "Select proper parares<br />");
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#new_registration").validate({
        rules: {
            parares_a: {
                validateParares: true,
            },
            parares_b: {
                validateParares: true,
            },
            parares_c: {
                validateParares: true,
            },
            parares_d: {
                validateParares: true,
            }
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            console.log(errorList);
            if(typeof(errorMap.parares_a) !='undefined' ||
              typeof(errorMap.parares_b) !='undefined' ||
              typeof(errorMap.parares_c) !='undefined' ||
               typeof(errorMap.parares_d) !='undefined') {
                $('#parares_error_output').html('Select proper parares<br />');
            } else {
                $('#parares_error_output').html('');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#submit").click(function(){

        if(validator.form()){
            alert("This form seems valid. Click 'Ok' to submit.");
        }

    });
});
```

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r_yash/arfucq2s/2/

Comment: This solution gives birth to a new problem. Now no other errors are displayed.