# How to manually append custom errors to jQuery Validation Plugin errors list?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin for a complicated form. Though it works great for basic things, my form contains some complicated validations. I tried using addMethod(), but ended up having multiple error messages, where there should only be one. Here's the question I posted about it, if you want to take a look -
[How to make user select "yes" from at least one of multiple select tags using jQuery Validation Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666431/how-to-make-user-select-yes-from-at-least-one-of-multiple-select-tags-using-jq)

But now I want to take a different approach. I want to use pure jQuery (instead of Validation Plugin) to do the complicated part of validations. But I want to append the errors thus generated to the errors list generated by the Plugin. I should be able to define the error message and error placement.

I tried going through Plugin source code, but it is too complicated for me. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make complax validation, you need to build your own regex (which is what jquery validation plugin is bases on). Regex is pretty simple and can be reusable if you have the same pattern in different places.

You can test your regex at: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

and check whether the pattern you created is valid.

Here is a regex guide for help: [Regex tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Basically I wouldn't recommend on making your validation on the client logic, this isn't a good practice at all, since the client side can be easily reached and manipulated. Instead, Use your server side for validation, It is much safer.

Comment: I don't want to build anything similar to Jquery Validation Plugin. I am happy with jQuery and JavaScript itself. I just want to copy the way (return method, formatting and all) in which Validation Plugin produces errors. So that all the errors in the form (plugin and non-plugin) will behave similarly.
Again, I don't want to copy Plugin logic, just the error format.
Secondly, I am applying dual validation (JavaScript and PHP). So no worries on that front.

Comment: But the error format itself is a regex. When you say you want to copy the error format, you basically say I want to copy the regex used by jquery validation plugin. There is no validation without regex, unless you use alerts or if\else\switch statements in order to specify your validations.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! But I can't even figure where to start. Isn't there any method by which I can append my custom created error to the existing error list of the plugin, defining message as well as placement?

Comment: I provided here a regex tutorial, which will help you build your own custom regex, explaining all from beginning to end. There is no custom created error methods in client side logic, as validation isn't meant to be on the client logic, but the tutorial should walk you through just fine :)

Comment: I have edited the question and following details to better explain what I want to do. Can you please give it a try?

Comment: After a brief look at the source code, jquery plugin is using url methods to replace the regex, meaning the regex is stored somewhere else and they are using method to communicate with the regex, instead of exposing it, I guess in order to try and avoid security break (but not sure). It is going to be tricky for you to try and use the exect way the plugin work. Study the regex syntax and work according to it, it will give you much more control over your validation and it will be much more simpler.